# Unable to resolve dependencies ( Some dependencies are not constructed ) issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In .NET Core, I am getting the issue of dependency resolution.
I have the following class hierarchy.

```
public abstract class TestBaseConfigs
{
      //some base configs
}

public class ChildDfx1Configs : TestBaseConfigs
{
   //some specific child configs.
}

public class ChildDfx2Configs : TestBaseConfigs
{
   //some specific child configs2
}

public interface ITest<T>
{
    void Calculate();
}

public class Dfx1Calc : ITest<ChildDfx1Configs >
{
    void Calculate()   //implemented method from interface
    {
    }

}

public class Dfx2Calc : ITest<ChildDfx2Configs>
{
    void Calculate()   //implemented method from interface
    {
    }
}

var currencyExchangeSettings = Configuration.GetSection("DfxCurrencyExchangeSettings");

var useDfx1CurrencyExchange = currencyExchangeSettings["UseDfx1CurrencyExchange"];

if (Convert.ToBoolean(useDfx1CurrencyExchange))
{
    services.AddScoped<ITest<ChildDfx1Configs>, Dfx1Calc>();  not works.. 
    services.AddScoped<ITest<TestBaseConfigs>, Dfx1Calc>(); //this also doesn't work as well.

         

}
```

and the constructor of class where the above dependency needed to be passed in.

```
public TranslationFeeManager(IChargesRepository chargesRepository, ITest<TestBase> currencyConversionManager)
{
    _chargesRepository = chargesRepository;
    _currencyConversionManager = currencyConversionManager;
}
```

Somehow ITest does not resolved. Dont know why. What could be the reight solution?
Can any body help me here ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the error message as well?

Comment: Well it wont resolve since in the provided example "ChildDfx1" really does not exists. Also don't you have to make void Calculate() into public? Also also you wrote DfxCalc not Dfx1Calc?

Comment: Perhaps declaring generic parameter `T` as `in` helps: `interface ITest<in T>`

Comment: You are registering `DfxCalc` as `ITest<ChildDfx1>` but in your provided code there is no  `DfxCalc` and no `ChildDfx1` just [...]Config objects

Comment: see the edited post again please.

Comment: I use your `services.AddScoped<ITest<ChildDfx1Configs>, Dfx1Calc>();` is ok. But I set it outside `if`, please try to set breakpoint at if to check. The second won't work because Dfx1Calc 's interface is ITest<ChildDfx1Configs>.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean **Dfx1Calc** instead of **DfxCalc** when adding services?

Comment: Yes, I mean Dfx1Calc